# Можно ли в шапке таблицы указать позиционирование текста?

Tags: html

Можно ли в html сделать так, чтобы текст отобразился в ячейке таблички так же как на рисунке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ибо оно позиционирует друг за другом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опишите более подробно, что вам требуется.

Comment: что бы вторая строка и третья были под словом Прайс, и небольшой отступ (два, три пробела) между словом Цена и Прайс, надеюсь так понятнее

Comment: Вариант не запрещенный - можно просто налепить &nbsp; для увеличения отступа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<table>
  <thead align="left">
    <tr>
      <th>Цiна</th>
      <th>Прайс</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Фактична<br />Нормативна</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Всё хорошо, пока не появятся линии. Замучаетесь линии расставлять.

Comment: @nick_n_a Какие линии?

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
 .th {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<th class=".th"><div>Цiна</div><div>Прайс Фактична Нормативна</div></th>
```